# ElasticSearch throwing 400 when deleting index on python

Tags: python, rest, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, http-status-code-400

I am getting a 400 error when trying to delete an index from elastic search using the python api

```
res = es.indices.delete(index=index_name)
```

and we are getting this exception

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'illegal_argument_exception')
```

However when deleting the index manually through postman, it works. It's also worth noting we don't get this error everyday which is very odd. Also just for note, this is a relatively big search index, not sure if that has to do with anything though (>10gb). We have also checked that the index exists before getting this error.

Comment: What error do you get in the ES server logs?

Comment: no I don't think I have set this up yet

Comment: Of course you have, by default ES will log errors in its log file, look into your `/var/log/elasticsearch` folder.

Comment: Sounds like a formatting error, can you give us more details on index name. Maybe yo postman query

Comment: Read the ES logs. Often, this might because there's a snapshot happening on this index while you're trying to delete it.